# Vuex dynamic values in actions

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using some classes that require something from localStorage as params. And I try to use these classes inside vuex actions. But when the script is loaded the value is set and even if localStorage updated the value in vuex action is not changed.

For example.

someService.js

```
export default class {
  constructor (token) {
    this.headers = {headers: { Authorization: token }}
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
import someService from '@/services/someService'
const myService = new someService(localStorage.getItem('token'))

const actions = {
  myService.stuff()
  // do stuff
}
```

This way when you call someService even after login the token always is always null because the class is instantiated only at the beginning.

So the question how can I get the current value of "token" after its changed. Do I need to reinstantiate for each action?

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should  re-instantiate after your token changes

Answer (score 1):

I've had to deal with this too, and I've ended up re-instantiating the object.

I'm using axios, but it would be similar in most other cases.

```
const someService = () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: myServerUrl,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}
  })
}
const actions = {
  someService().get('items')
}
```

axios also allows changing the default this way, and then you wouldn't need to include the authorization

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
```

but that wouldn't really solve your problem either, as when you set

```
const myService = new someService(localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

you place the token into it at initialization time. so another option would be...

someService.js

```
export default class {
  constructor (token) {
    this.headers = {headers: { Authorization: token }}
  },
  updateToken (token) {
    this.headers.headers.Authorization = token
  }
}
```

actions.js

```
import someService from '@/services/someService'
const myService = new someService(localStorage.getItem('token'))

const actions = {
  myService.stuff()
  // do stuff
  // log in
  // get new token
  myService.updateToken(localStorage.getItem('token'))
  // do stuff with new token
  myService.stuff()
}
```